# Bold OR and confidence interval with tbl_regression (gt_summary)

Tags: r, gtsummary

I use the awesome package `gt_summary` to perform my work. I have an actual table made with this code to describe a logistic regression:

```
tbl_regression(GLMlombalgie, 
               exponentiate = TRUE, 
               pvalue_fun = ~style_pvalue(.x, digits = 3),
               estimate_fun = partial(style_ratio, digits = 3)) %>% bold_labels() %>% italicize_levels() %>% bold_p()-> tablemultivariee
```

Is it possible to hide p-value BUT bold significant odds ratio and confidence interval?

Thanks !

I already try to look at the Daniel Sjoberg documentation, but without finding the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that! Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.2'

tbl <-
  glm(response ~ age + grade, data = trial, family = binomial) |> 
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) |> 
  # hide the p.value column
  modify_column_hide(p.value) |> 
  # bold sig cells
  modify_table_styling(
    columns = c(estimate, ci), # use `show_header_names()` to see underlying column names
    rows = p.value < 0.2, # change your significance threshold here
    text_format = "bold"
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2023-09-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: It works perfectly ! Thank you for your response and also for all you do with the gtsummary library !